# debugging xcode 4: says it's running application on device, but nothing actually happens

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, debugging, xcode4

I can't debug my application on my device with xcode 4. The application builds, links and signs and installs on the device but when xcode 4 says "running  on Dev iPad 2" nothing happens on the device.

I've quit and restarted xcode, and restarted the Mac. No difference.

The only warning it gives me is "warning: no debug symbols in executable (-arch armv7)". I'm not sure if that's related to my problem.

If I start the application manually on the device, it works.

I created a small test app. It compiled and ran on the device with no problem.

What could be causing this in my application?

Comment: Seems that no debug point was found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this could be fixed by deleting the app from the device, and also deleting the provisioning profile from the device as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check the name of your executable in Build Settings - specifically, make sure that Debug and Release versions have the same name. It may be trying to run an executable that isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Build settings: `Strip Linked Product`. In my case I had to set this setting to `No`. After that the warning was gone.